# How can I jump beginning of the buffer under import section in python-mode

Tags: python, buffers

I am using [`beginning-of-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/beginning_002dof_002dbuffer.html) to the jump beginning of a buffer.

Is it possible to achive same behavior but to the first line under the `import or` from` section in the Python mode.

In this example I want to jump to 17th line. There could be multiple modules under `from ... import (` and there could be also a new-line in between `from ...` and `import...` lines.

```
1:  #!/usr/bin/env python3
2: 
3:  import os
4:  import sys
5:  import textwrap
6:  import time
7:  from broker.utils.tools import log
8: 
9:  import zc.lockfile
10: from ipdb import launch_ipdb_on_exception
11: 
12: from broker.utils import (
13:     CacheType,
14:     StorageID,
15: )
16:
17: # <== jump here
18: 
19: def _main():
20:     from my_module.utils.tools import work
21:
22:     work()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not tried anything due to my lack of knowledge in lisp coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of some existing function that does this. But there are many simple ways to achieve this; two commands you could use are:

EDIT in response to your first comment

So I guess after finding the last "import", you could just continue to look for the first empty line.

SECOND EDIT in response to your second comment

To exclude 'searching for/from' "import"s in 'the body' of the file, we can just limit the range for the search to "import", e.g. as follows:

```lisp
(defun my-alternative-jump-to-end-of-imports ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let (end)
    (save-excursion
      (forward-line 3)
      (setq end (point)))
    (while (search-forward "import" end t)
      (save-excursion
        (forward-line 3)
        (setq end (point))))
    (while (and (not (eobp))
                (not (member (thing-at-point 'line t) '("" "\n"))))
      (forward-line))
    (if (bolp)
        (forward-line)
      (insert "\n\n"))))
```

You can play a little with the number of lines for searching forward. It is not perfect, but I guess it works fine for 99% of the cases.

END EDITS

I would suggest that you take some time to read a few chapters of [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html) (or read it right inside of Emacs) and study the above functions; it is not so much work, and Emacs becomes so much more fun to use.

Comment: Thank you, I will study the referenced book. If there is new-line in between the  `from` and `import` lines it jumps into first new-line location. Would it be possible to pass over those new-lines as well? I updated my question based on that. Seems like complexity of the question increased :(

Comment: I've edited the answer in response to your comment

Comment: Ah if there is something like `from my_module.imports import connect` at the bottom of page inside a module(`def main():` ) it jumps below that instead of the top modules (I have updated my question according to that as well). I will find way to ignore that , other than it works great

Comment: Okay... I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated your patient help

Comment: After `#!/usr/bin/env python3`at the 3rd line  I may have doc string like `"""Doc definition..."""`, jump may end up at that line; I manage to by-pass it by changing first `(forward-line 3)` into `(forward-line 5)`. Can we also suppress its output in the minibuffer?

Comment: Ah, I accidentally left the print statement in the code. So, now I have removed it...

Comment: I am able code pretty well in Python and C but I am having difficulties to compile the emacs lisp code in my mind  ; I feel like it becomes much difficult to learn a new language when you get older :-( @dalanicolai